# How to display a message when the mouse and keyboard not used for two minutes?

Tags: c#

I want that my windows form application show me message when my mouse and keyboard are inactive for 2 minutes anyone can help me?

I have WinForms application written in C# . it is time doctor application and I want that my app show me message when mouse and keyboard not used for two minutes.

```cs
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-CVVIN92;Initial Catalog=PizzaShop;Integrated Security=True");
for(int i=0; i < dataGridsorder.Rows.Count; i++)
{              
    SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand(@"INSERT into Orders(Customer,Mobile,Date,MainType,SubType,OrderType,Discount,Net_Total) VALUES('"+dataGridsorder.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value+ "','" + dataGridsorder.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value + "','" + dataGridsorder.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value + "','" + dataGridsorder.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value + "','" + dataGridsorder.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value + "','" + dataGridsorder.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value + "','" + dataGridsorder.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value + "','" + dataGridsorder.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value + "')",conn);
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();

    MessageBox.Show("Your order is successfully completed...", "Information Messsage", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
```

Like this MessageBox, I want to show if mouse not moved.

Comment: [Programmatically determining whether a Windows user is idle](https://www.mking.net/blog/programmatically-determining-whether-a-windows-user-is-idle)

Comment: this is the manual way to doing it but i want it auto show me message when input is in active . thankyou in advance.

Comment: See the answers [How do I determine idle time in my C# application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13210142/10216583)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer?view=netcore-3.1) that triggers every X-seconds. You could then use the link from @JQSOFT to check if two minutes has passed [since the last input](https://www.mking.net/blog/programmatically-determining-whether-a-windows-user-is-idle). If it has, show a [messagebox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.messagebox?view=netcore-3.1).